# Sitecore: call methode from context menu item

Tags: asp.net, command, field, sitecore, fieldtype

I have created my own fieldtype ( extension of TreelistEx ).
For this extension i added a second context menu item ( by default TreelistEx already has a "edit" menu item ).

I started off with linking this menu item with a command. This works fine but it doesn't realy answer to my requirements. I would need the menu item to execute a method located in the fieldtype.

TreelistEx works like this with the "edit" menu item. There is no reference to a command ( i checked Commands.config and plenty of other config files ) yet it reaches the Edit method in TreelistEx.cs

Does anyone know how i can achieve the same result ?

*( Alternativly: is there a way to pass the source property of the fieldtype to a command )*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the core database you have define a
/sitecore/system/Field types/List Types/YOURTreelistEx

provide a control and set in the web.config below `<controlSources>`
or provide a class and Assembly, i guess you have done this?
you need to make your own control, or class

And you have in the core db create the item
/sitecore/system/Field types/List Types/YOURTreelistEx/Menu/YOURButton

In the Message field set yourfield:yourbutton

Modify the void IMessageHandler.HandleMessage(Message message) there is also the Command call to the Edit

```
public override void HandleMessage(Message message)
{
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) message, "message");
      if (!(message["id"] == this.ID))
        return;
      switch (message.Name)
      {
        case "treelist:edit":
          Context.ClientPage.Start((object) this, "Edit");
          break;
         case "yourfield:yourbutton":
        //Call Your code;
          break;
      }
}
```

See for Example [Creating a custom Sitecore Field](https://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/best-practice-blogs/martin-knudsen/posts/2012/09/creating-a-custom-sitecore-field.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Jan, just what i was looking for. I was missing the HandleMessage bit.

Comment: Small issue, when i use this the edit page is shown but no parameters from the source are passed.
( like datasource and what templates to include )

Comment: You can read the form values: for example  string currentitemUri = WebUtil.GetFormValue("__CurrentItem");
            var currentitemItemUri = new global::Sitecore.Data.ItemUri(currentitemUri); 
            var item = global::Sitecore.Data.Database.GetItem(currentitemItemUri);  and you have the (saved version) of the item, and access to everyting..

Comment: I don't think we're on the same line.

The standard edit function of the treelistex doesn't work properly anymore. I can't add code to the sitecore implementation of treelistex so i don't see how your code can help me out here.